# IBM Worklight - Unable to load index.html in a Dojo app

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created sample Wokrlight Project with Dojo library (default template project).

The Android version of app runs fine in the Android Emulator showing the content of index.html. But When I run the same app in a device, it first shows IBM splash image and then the following error:

> Application Error The Connection to the server was unsuccessful.
>   (file:///data/data/com.HelloWorklight/files/www/default/index.html)

Here are the steps I followed.

1. Create New Hybrid Application Worklight Project "HelloWorklight" with Application Name as "HelloWorklight".
2. Added Dojo Library using "Configure Javascript Library" and click on "finish"
   == This created a Project Named "HelloWorklight" in Eclipse.
3. Now I added Android phones and tablets in "application-descriptor.xml" (Using Design Tab Only)
   == Now I can See "android" SubFolder inside "Apps\HelloWorklight\"
4. Then I right-clicked on "android" ( from Apps\HelloWorklight ) and Then selected "Run As" > "Android Studio Project"
   == This created One more project (Android Project) in eclipse as "HelloWorklightHelloWorklightAndroid"
5. Now I right-click on "HelloWorklightHelloWorklightAndroid" and select "Run As" > "Android Application"
   == This opens AVD / Android Emulator with default Device and I can see the index.html content on the Android Emulator screen.
6. Now When My Test Android Device is connected to system, "Run As .." option promts me to select Emulator / Device. When I select Device It installs the app on Device and runs Application.
   == Here I see first IBM Splash Screen the the above error.

**NOTE**

1. I tried running application using .apk exported. which turns out to
   be showing same error message. When I check the .apk file it has all
   contents required (html, js and css files). Even the location of
   file is
   **file:**///data/data/com.HelloWorklight/files/www/default/index.html
2. The application runs on Emulator Even if Worklight Development
       Server is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step #4 is not needed and incorrect:

- You should choose "Android Studio Project" [only if you actually have **Android Studio** installed in your computer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and if you actually intended on using it. Otherwise it will fail:

  > Failed Running Android Studio: Specify location of Android Studio in
  >   Window->Preferences->Worklight
- Choosing it anyway, is not what generates the Android project; After adding the Android environment to your application, the Android project is being *auto-generated* for you by Worklight Studio.

I have followed your steps in Worklight 6.1.0  and tested in both AVD and device, and could not reproduce.

Try the following steps and tell me the result:

1. In Eclipse, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> if in Mac) and add the `Dojo Library Requests` view
2. Press the "play"-like button to disable it (it is enabled by default)
3. Re-build and deploy
4. Re-run and test in the device
5. Familiarize yourself with Dojo in Worklight: [Working with the Dojo Library Project that serves Dojo resources](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/cdojolibprjsetupwl.html)

Comment: I have Android Studio Installed and I have set location of Android studio in preferences. Also, I have tried after disabling Dojo Library Request. Also, checked that all resources includes are using local path not from cloud server.

Comment: Are you at all *using* Android Studio? Is a new application w/out Dojo working or also failing?

Comment: I created new project again and disabled the "Dojo Library Requests" in start, and run using Android Studio. .. it's working now